# Zend Session destroyed if page requested too quick

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

My application is not built on MVC pattern but it partially using Zend Framework components like Config, Loader, Session, Auth, Service and XmlRpc.

Recently I have discovered that in some occasions, if user would navigate through pages too fast or press <kbd>F5</kbd> too quick, his session would be destroyed and he would be logged out of the system. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753481/zend-session-expires-when-refreshed-many-times) but his solution did not helped me to solve this issue.

#### How the application works

Session Config:

```
cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"
name = "myApplicationName"
remember_me_seconds = 864000
save_path = "/path/to/my/session/storage/"
save_handler = "files"
strict = true
use_only_cookies = true
```

On page initialisation:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(CONFIG_DIR . 'session.ini');

Zend_Session::setOptions($config->toArray());

Zend_Session::start();
```

Account Controller:

```
function __construct(...)
{
    /**
     * @var $session Zend_Session_Namespace
     */
    $session = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Auth');

    if(isset($session->identity))
    {
        Zend_Session::rememberMe();
    }
}
```

Log out process:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    Zend_Session::destroy(TRUE);
}
```

Did any one else experienced this issue and have some clues what can be wrong and how to fix it?

#### Update

I have disabled `Zend_Session::rememberMe()` and everything seems to work fine now. As I understand, on every request this method refresh `session_id` and rename session file, and due to read/write performance issue it cannot find newly created session, and because of that session handler is lost.
Just wondering, would changing session storage to database could fix this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution.? I am facing the same problem..

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem before with raw PHP. The problem was that `session_regenerate_id()` was being called too frequently (every HTTP request).

Check to see if something (whether the Zend framework or some other code) is regenerating your session ID. You might be running into an HTTP race condition where the ID it gets is not as new as the one PHP expects.

Answer (score 0):

I use it and havent experienced this problem. I would recomend to a) track your save path and see if there are any scripts modifying the rights of this path b) take a closer look if the session handler can open files simultaneously.

Simply put: Zend_Session doesn't do any magic by itself, it is a really simple wrapper.

Comment: Session save path is already pointing to a custom folder, I'm just wondering can it be a file system issue, for example slow writing as `Zend_Session::rememberMe()`does change session_id all the time after page request.